# How to ensure that tweaks to a SPSS Model will trigger adjustments to a python algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, binding, spss

I'm working on a proof of concept on how to make SPSS and Python talk to each other. We have a model in SPSS that routinely will be tweaked and adjusted (to the data-set and variables and overall rules), we would like those changes to automatically trigger appropriate changes in a corresponding python algorithm.

I've been reading up on bindings and learned from some overflow questions that there are two ways of integrating SPSS and python (one where the python block lives inside SPSS syntax, and one external situation that lives in python that I believe works by importing the SPSS library).

We'd ideally like to work in the second integration type, externally in a python environment instead of in the SPSS syntax. So I was wondering if anyone has tips on which python functions and classes (ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/20.0/en/pythonplugin/Manuals/Python_Integration_Package_for_IBM_SPSS_Statistics.pdf) from the python integration for SPSS will work best. I'm thinking we'll need to create a middle man python program within the SPSS block that will connect the SPSS model to an outside python algorithm.

Can anyone assist? And apologies if this is too broad, I tried to make this as specific as possible but I can provide more details if that's needed.